# css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have a drop down navigation menu in which some of the title should not navigate to other page when clicked(these title open a drop down menu when clicked on) while others should navigate (these dont have dropdown and navigate directly).However, both types have `href` defined to them

To solve this i added the following css for the former type of titles

```
pointer-events: none;
```

and it is working fine.But since this property is not supported by IE, i am looking for some work-around.
The annoying thing is that **i don't have access and privilege to change the HTML and JavaScript code** completely.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a way to gain access to the HTML and scripts? Try talking to whoever gave you the task.

Comment: @Kyle Its not exactly a problem of privilege,there are some technical difficulties also to modify the html/javascript code

Comment: Here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: Note that `pointer-events` is now in IE11+

Comment: @davidstorey - it's actually still not supported in IE11, I'm running some tests on IE9+ and none work, when I try to `getComputedStyle` I get a `visiblePainted`.

Comment: IE11 won't ever support pointer-events (especially because 11 is/should be its last version). However it supports a pretty easy **workaround** (no need to use _layers_ and/or JavaScript): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10276157/1207195

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Pointer-events is a Mozilla hack and where it has been implemented in Webkit browsers, you can't expect to see it in IE browsers for another million years.

There is however a solution I found:

[Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

This uses a plugin that uses some not well known/understood properties of Javascript to take the mouse event and send it to another element.

There is also another Javascript solution [here](http://jsbin.com/uhuto).

**Update for October 2013**: apparently it's coming to IE in v11. [Source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events). Thanks Tim.

Comment: Documentation of ie9 says it supports this property(i've not tried ie9 yet however).Anyway, i already had ideas in my mind which are given in the links but as i was looking for some css specific solution i cannot use them. I will try to modify the html/js code rather spending time on this problem.Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: The page was down when I checked, but here's some code the author wrote for the ext.js library that accomplishes the same: http://code.google.com/p/ext-ux-datadrop/source/browse/trunk/src/Override.js

Comment: While this workaround will forward the event, it will not forward the actual click. For example, an input field will fire a focus event without gaining focus. A button will fire a click event but not be clicked, etc...

Comment: At W3C, this issue went [under debate due to click-hijacking](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Aug/0176.html). Rule of thumb: as soon as W3C publish the candidate recommendation, IE team will implement it & there's always a lesson in [haste makes waste](http://bit.ly/OifiM4). Besides, Mozilla [said it all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) "**Warning:** *The use of pointer-events in CSS for non-SVG elements is experimental. The feature used to be part of the CSS3 UI draft specification but, due to many open issues, has been postponed to CSS4.*"

Comment: According to caniuse.com, CSS pointer events are coming to IE 11. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: I made a simpler js version (not using css pointer events) - getting the element by using elementFromPoint http://jsfiddle.net/3NDaL/3/ - hope it will help

Comment: yeah, you are right. i'll upvote this as soon as you edit your answer but i've managed to find a css-only solution for this problem.

Comment: `"you can't expect to see it in IE browsers for another million years."`
Took only 3 years...

Comment: @eyurdakul why don't you share your solution then..?

Comment: @Sumit: I guess I vastly underestimated Microsoft on this one.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks i guess everyone underestimated Microsoft. Current IE development is awesome, especially status.modern.ie. They only need to kill IE8 and 9 ASAP and we're good to go into sweet heaven of modern development!

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks "you can't expect to see it in IE browsers for another million years." - IE 11 has it

Comment: Yes, yes we've covered this ground. This answer was constructed during the time when Microsoft were considered to be less than stellar at browser building. Times have changed, but the answer remains.

Answer (score 20):

Here is another solution that is  very easy to implement with 5 lines of code:

1. Capture the 'mousedown' event for the top element (the element you want to turn off pointer events).
2. In the 'mousedown' hide the top element.
3. Use 'document.elementFromPoint()' to get the underlying element.
4. Unhide the top element.
5. Execute the desired event for the underlying element.

Example:

```
//This is an IE fix because pointer-events does not work in IE
$(document).on('mousedown', '.TopElement', function (e) {

    $(this).hide();
    var BottomElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    $(this).show();
    $(BottomElement).mousedown(); //Manually fire the event for desired underlying element

    return false;

});
```

Comment: This worked for me. I prefer small fixes that I can put into my js code instead adding a lot of polyfills  ;)

Comment: This is a creative solution, I like it. The only problem is this adds unnecessary processing to browsers where the point-events _do_ work. It would be great to make this execute conditionally IE browsers only.

Comment: I agree, its a quickly implementable to a perplexing issue, but in fact in my implementation of it, I only apply it if the browser is IE, you place it inside this check: if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {  ... logic goes here .. }

Comment: this works very well! since ie 11 supposedly started supporting pointer-events, I just wrap it inside this clause: if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') > 0)    THANKS!

Answer (score 17):

There's a workaround for IE - use inline SVG and set pointer-events="none" in SVG.
See my answer in [How to make Internet Explorer emulate pointer-events:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385213/how-to-make-internet-explorer-emulate-pointer-eventsnone)

Answer (score 11):

It's worth mentioning that specifically for IE, `disabled=disabled` works for anchor tags:

```
<a href="contact.html" onclick="unleashTheDragon();" disabled="disabled">Contact</a>
```

IE treats this as an `disabled` element and does not trigger click event. However, `disabled` is not a valid attribute on an anchor tag. Hence this won't work in other browsers. For them `pointer-events:none` is required in the styling.

**UPDATE 1**: So adding following rule feels like a cross-browser solution to me

**UPDATE 2**: For further compatibility,  because IE will not form styles for anchor tags with `disabled='disabled'`, so they will still *look* active. Thus, `a:hover{}` rule and styling is a good idea:

```
a[disabled="disabled"] {
        pointer-events: none; /* this is enough for non-IE browsers */
        color: darkgrey;      /* IE */
    }
        /* IE - disable hover effects */   
        a[disabled="disabled"]:hover {
            cursor:default;
            color: darkgrey;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
```

Working on Chrome, IE11, and IE8.
Of course, above CSS assumes anchor tags are rendered with `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: This didn't work for me. In IE9-10 onclick functions still do execute.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a small script implementing this feature (inspired by the [Shea Frederick blog article](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/) that Kyle mentions):

- [Pointer Events Polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill).

Comment: This doesn't work if the elements are anchor tags, I believe. At least, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I spent almost two days on finding the solution for this problem and I found this at last.

This uses javascript and jquery.

[(GitHub) pointer_events_polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill)

This could use a javascript plug-in to be downloaded/copied.
Just copy/download the codes from that site and save it as `pointer_events_polyfill.js`. Include that javascript to your site.

`<script src="JS/pointer_events_polyfill.js></script>`

Add this jquery scripts to your site

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    PointerEventsPolyfill.initialize({});
});
```

And don't forget to include your jquery plug-in.

It works! I can click elements under the transparent element. I'm using IE 10. I hope this can also work in IE 9 and below.

**EDIT:** Using this solution does not work when you click the textboxes below the transparent element. To solve this problem, I use focus when the user clicks on the textbox.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("theTextbox").focus();
```

JQuery:

```
$("#theTextbox").focus();
```

This lets you type the text into the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

Cover the offending elements with an invisible block, using a pseudo element: `:before` or `:after`

```
a:before {
//IE No click hack by covering the element.
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  content:' ';
}
```

Thus you're click lands on the parent element. No good, if the parent is clickable, but works well otherwise.

Comment: I used a similar idea with the disabled attribute. In IE adding the disabled attribute prevents click events, but if there are children they will still trigger the click. covering the children so they are not clickable is a great solution to this. I had to use a background color with opacity 0 to have IE register there was an actual element there.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution to solve this problem. I use jQuery to set the `href`-attribute to `javascript:;` (not ' ', or the browser will reload the page) if the browser window width is greater than 1'000px. You need to add an ID to your link. Here's what I'm doing:

```
// get current browser width
var width = $(window).width();
if (width >= 1001) {

    // refer link to nothing
    $("a#linkID").attr('href', 'javascript:;'); 
}
```

Maybe it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnClientClick = "return false;"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also just "not" add a url inside the `<a>` tag, i do this for menus that are `<a>` tag driven with drop downs as well.  If there is not drop down then i add the url but if there are drop downs with a `<ul> <li>` list i just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues:

1. I faced this issue in a directive, i fixed it adding a  as its parent element and making pointer-events:none for that
2. The above fix did not work for select tag, then i added **cursor:text** (which was what i wanted) and it worked for me

If a normal cursor is needed you could add **cursor:default**

Answer (score -2):

Best solution:

```
.disabled{filter: alpha(opacity=50);opacity: 0.5;z-index: 1;pointer-events: none;}
```

Runs perfectly on all browsers

Comment: Except for IE version < 11, where pointer events isn't supported. I think you missed the point.