# Transparent image over an element with :hover

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a partially transparent background/image (png logo with shadow) positioned over (using higher z-index or in some other way) some element (menu), without the top image (logo) interfering with the `:hover` behavior of the partially covered element (menu)?

Currently I have a div with a background image (logo) covering the menu, so the menu elements never get any `:hover` triggers (and can't be clicked either). I'd like the div to be displayed as it is now, but all mouse related clicks and hover events would pass trough the div to the menu as if the menu was on top.

Comment: an example would help us understand better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) is the answer CSS provides to do this.

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/pointer-events (works everywhere except IE10 and older)

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/7D5Jt/

If the browser support for `pointer-events` is not acceptable, you'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: great, thanks. How would you use JS to achieve this on Opera/IE?

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie, hope it works for Opera too.

Comment: Good find. I can confirm that both the solutions in that answer work for Opera.

Comment: You should be aware that the javascript dom events also respect pointer-events:none so you cant use this if you want to maintain mouse clicks etc