# Watermark label positioned over top of select stops click propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-propagation

I've created a watermark/hint solution for a drop down where I absolutely position a label over top of a select element.

Unfortunately, when the user clicks where the label is, the drop down doesn't open - obviously the click is being blocked by the label. Is there any way to have it so when a user clicks on the label, the drop down is opened? I understand you can't open a dropdown via javascript but can you do something like hide the label when the click fires?

**Edit:** Creating a custom drop down like gmail does on their dropdowns is not a viable option.

Comment: yes, but we need some kind of demo or source code.

Comment: didn't think it really required one but here you go anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/ajbeaven/Sj7CN/1/

Comment: I'm curious: what did you end up doing?

Comment: Just what you suggested. Used the pointer-events css for browsers that supported that and then hid the label on `:hover` for the others. Tried doing fade effects but couldn't get them working nicely unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS can handle that: add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) to the `label`.

That's supported in all modern browsers.. except for current versions of IE (and Opera), so you'll still unfortunately have to [use JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie).

Comment: That javascript solution won't open the drop down, all it does is fire the click event on the select element.

Comment: Ah.. you're right, sorry. As you stated in your question, it is indeed impossible to open a `select` via JavaScript. I'm not sure how you can work around this, short of creating your own dropdown (which you already said is not viable for you). I've just tried a few ideas out, and I really can't come up with anything.

Comment: Maybe for only IE and Opera, hide the `label` on `:hover`. I know it's not the same, but it's the only thing that comes to mind.