# Transparent background image on top of page

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that I would like to display on top of my webpage, or better explained, imagine the background image as a watermark. I would like to place this as a filter over my webpage. So that every page has this "watermark"

I've managed to do this by setting the image transparent. But the problem is that unless i set z-index to lets say -10000, then the image is considered to be "on top" of everything else and thus my links are unclickable.

Any suggestions to how to achieve what I'm trying to do without making links unclickable?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think there is a way to do this. An image is either on top, obscuring everything, or underneath, being obscured by everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [pointer-events](http://www.webkit.org/specs/PointerEventsProperty.html) on the overlay

```
#overlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

There's a good post on it here - http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/

Comment: Thanks for your input! But unfortunatly i need IE7 support amongst other things so i cant use this yet... :(

Comment: It's always bloody IE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie