# Detect support for pointer-events:none on SVG

Tags: svg, safari, modernizr, browser-feature-detection, pointer-events

I have found an issue where trying to use pointer-events:none on SVG's in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows does not work, but works perfectly on div's. How would I go about detecting support for this using; Vanilla JavaScript or Modernizr to provide fallback for unique use cases like this. Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/DLEsn/75/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="pass_through_svg">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="rgba(0,0,255,0.4)"/>
</svg>
<div class="pass_through"></div>
<div class="red_block"></div>
```

Comment: Safari on Windows hasn't been updated since 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SVG not recognising pointer-events:none](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972730/svg-not-recognising-pointer-eventsnone)