# How to ignore div's of particular class when getting element from point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-swiffy

I'm using Google Swiffy animations, which are contained within `<div>`s that cover the entire area of our document.  There are several layers of these animations.  Much of the animation is transparent, but we don't have the option of cropping out the whitespace.  For example, our web application is `1000px x 500px`, and there are several layers of animation `<div>`s that are absolutely positioned at 0, 0 and are also `1000px x 500px`.

Beneath the animation layers, there are interactive controls, buttons and links.  On many browsers, excluding IE of course, we can simply use the CSS `pointer-events: none;` style and the clicks passes right through the animations to the controls.  However, a few customers still use IE, so we need to support them.

I've been experimenting with `document.elementFromPoint();`, however, it only gives me the animation div itself.  Stepping out of that div using parentNode also doesn't seem helpful because there is no translation point.   I really need something like ActionScript's localToGlobal().

Is there a way to ignore all of these animations divs when using `elementFromPoint` so I can identify the intended click target?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a specific CSS3 property from mozilla.. Then I've found this post: [How to make Internet Explorer emulate pointer-events:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385213/how-to-make-internet-explorer-emulate-pointer-eventsnone)