# Workaround for 'poiner-events:none' in Opera

Tags: css, opera

I'm looking for a workaround that could give me the same result as the CSS pointer-events:none. Basically I have a div over image and I wan't to pass events to the image below.

As you can see it is not supported in the current version of Opera:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385213/how-to-make-internet-explorer-emulate-pointer-eventsnone can help

Comment: Be aware that you should find a workaround for both, MS IE and Opera.