# pointer-events: none not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pointer-events

I'm trying to disable the hyperlinks in my SharePoint 2013 list edit page. I used a content editor webpart and put `pointer-events : none`. It works fine on Google Chrome but doesn't work in IE . Is there any alternative to this? I just want the CSS alternative. My IE is version 10.

Comment: Is that a typo or did you really type `pointer-event: none` in your CSS? The property is `pointer-events` with an **S** at the end

Comment: @Bojangles Correct spelled in title, typo fixed now in question

Comment: yes i did put pointer-events . sorry for misspelling here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)

Answer (score 2):

[`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is not supported in IE 10 and there is no other similar CSS property.

Either a change in your markup or using a script is needed to solve that.

*Update*

Here is a sample using script.

I also styled the link so one can't see them as links, which actually could be used alone, based on if someone randomly clicks in the text and accidentally hits one, it would still be okay.

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a")).forEach(function(link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  cursor: text;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
Some text with <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"> a link </a> to click on
```

*Update 2*

Here is actually 2 posts that has a several ways of how this might be done (all script though but one),

- [css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)
- [How to make Internet Explorer emulate pointer-events:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385213/how-to-make-internet-explorer-emulate-pointer-eventsnone)

where [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18118092/2827823) doesn't use script.

---

*Update 3 based on comment*

To use the attribute `disabled='disabled'` one either need to add it server side so the anchor looks like this, `<a href="link" disabled="disabled">Link</a>`, or client side with a script like this

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a")).forEach(function(link) {

  link.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

});
```

```css
/*
a {
  cursor: text;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
*/
```

```html
Some text with <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"> a link </a> to click on
```

Comment: do you know any script for this @LGSon

Comment: @Revenant_01 Updated my answer with a sample

Comment: @Revenant_01 Made a small update again ... and now you can both accept and vote on answers :)

Comment: i tried using that script in my content editor webpart , but its not working

Comment: @Revenant_01 Make sure the script runs in the end of your body or in the onload/dom ready event.

Comment: yes . it loads in the pageload . u r sure there is no way we can not do it with CSS .

Comment: @Revenant_01 As we speak I'm testing another way. Will update my answer again soon if it works, or comment if not.

Comment: @Revenant_01 Didn't work what I tried, updated my answer with a couple of links, all (but one) uses script though.

Comment: i think [disabled] should work here . but my question here is how i can use it with the class . the class name is '.ms-formbody' . and i tried doing .ms-formbody[disabled]{}; but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Revenant_01 Added a 3:rd update for you, explaining that.