# iScroll is not detecting mouseup

Tags: jquery, events, iscroll, mouseup

http://jsfiddle.net/zyVUU/

In the fiddle, if I start dragging the div, then keeping the mousedown go to the over CSS box, leave the mouse (mouseup) and then come back to the orange div, the scroller follows the mouse.

It is not detecting the mouseup event. How can I force it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because that `div` has a `pointer-events: none;` property.

> The CSS property `pointer-events` allows authors to control under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of mouse events.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering this because of IE, and found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: What would be the opposite of none in this case?