# How do i add a mask on top of a bootstrap element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's carousel ( http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel ) to show a user submited gallery. Because it's user submited, it doesnt look very good with the rest of my website design thats why i want to add a layer mask on top off everything

Here is the mask : http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/2659/degrade.png
Unfortunatly, I'm unable to show that particular div...
It has to be non clickable because when a user click on a picture of the carousel, it opens  modal popup with the full sized picture.

My css (its using less but you get the idea):

```
.carousel {
  width: 292px;
  height: 163px;

  .carousel-inner {
    width: 292px;
    height: 163px;

    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
}

.carousel-control {
  margin-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 163px;
  opacity: 0.65;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

    &:hover.right {
      background-image: url('/assets/index/r_arrow.png');
    }

    &:hover.left {
      background-image: url('/assets/index/l_arrow.png');
    }
}
```

heres is my html:

```
<div class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <a href="popup_img1.htm"><img src="thumbnail1.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="popup_img2.htm"><img src="thumbnail2.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="popup_img3.htm"><img src="thumbnail3.jpg" /></a>
        </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control left" href=".carousel" data-slide="prev">&nbsp;</a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href=".carousel" data-slide="next">&nbsp;</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your cross-browser support needs, you could try giving the overlay `pointer-events: none`. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/pum3e/) of that.

If you insert `<div class="overlay"></div>` into `.carousel-inner`, give `.carousel-inner {position: relative;}` and

```
.overlay {
    background: url(http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/2659/degrade.png) top left no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

There's [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie) that gives information and links to solutions using javascript. Unfortunately, the resources for the accepted answer to the linked question have gone offline, but there is a fairly simple demonstration here: http://jsbin.com/uhuto

Comment: thanks for this! by the way, by the time of this comment the jsfiddle is not working, but still worth to read and check the other links

Comment: Hey @w3jimmy, no problem! I've updated the jsfiddle link with the latest CDN references for the Bootstrap dependencies.