# Is there any way to get a mouseover event when an element is covered up by another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Without calculating the element's position and then firing your own "event".

[original fiddle (can be fixed with z-index)](http://jsfiddle.net/ckaPU/)

[better fiddle (a situation where z-index can't work)](http://jsfiddle.net/PHXJ9/4/)

[image: example]

```
<div class='under'></div>
<div class='over'></div>

.over { 
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}

.under {
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  height:26px;
  width:26px;
  top:37px;
  left:37px;
  background:rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}
```

Comment: i think not but can i ask you why are you using it?

Comment: just to be clear, do you want the green to be Y whilst hovering over the blue aswell?

Comment: A [hack](http://jsfiddle.net/GLCPV/1/) for the original case. Though results seem to flicker in FF, all other browsers work fine...

Comment: i added another fiddle which explains the problem a little better. i want to know when the mouse is over green WHILE i am dragging blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've missed the point of your example, you can just add a z-index attribute to your CSS:

```
.over 
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
    z-index:1;
}

.under 
{
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:26px;
    width:26px;
    top:37px;
    left:37px;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: i added a more specific example. a guy above gave this link and it looks like a pretty decent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: i ended up calculating the coords myself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, you could put a z-index in your css:

```
.under {
    z-index:1;
 }
```

and then modify your JS:

```
under.on("mouseover", function() { 
                            blue.html("Y"); 
                            green.html("Y"); 
 });
```

**EDITED**
wrong link.

here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gracedescending/qm6Fq/)

Comment: thanks doesnt help for this guy, but i needed something exactly like that. very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Add `pointer-events:none;` to your `over` div:

```
.over {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
    pointer-events:none;
 }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ckaPU/1/

Comment: @Yusaf Khaliq I just follow what OP want and this is the easiest way

Comment: outstanding! but no ie10 or opera

Comment: @user1873073 IE is not supported pointer-events: [http://caniuse.com/pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events). You can try alternative way: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)