# pointer-events workaround

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

There are already some solution for IE to do the workaround for the pointer events.
However I am just a beginner and do not understand and cannot follow the guides in that solution.
[css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie/15367868?noredirect=1#comment21736908_15367868)

Yesterday, I found this new method. But somehow I cannot manage to do the trick.
Can anyone help me?
http://lea.verou.me/css3-secrets/#pointer-events-workaround

```
function noPointerEvents (element) {
    $(element).bind('click mouseover', function (evt) {
        this.style.display = 'none';
        var x = evt.pageX, y = evt.pageY,
            under = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
        this.style.display = '';
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(under).trigger(evt.type);
    });
}
```