# How can I activate the CSS hover state of an element below a block of text (w/o Javascript)?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid of elements over which I have an h1 text tag. Each of the grid elements has a hover action, and I would like to activate that hover action for the grid elements below the text. However, I cannot put the z-index of the grid elements higher, as that would obscure the text.

A basic idea of the html: (and here's an actually useful JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/evd3v/)

```
<div id="background" class="header">
</div>
<div id="overlay">
    <table>...</table>  <!-- A grid that covers the background image -->
</div>
<h1 id="title" class="title">My Page Title</h1>
<h2 id="detail" class="title">Designed by Me</h2>
```

Comment: Can you please provide some code or even better a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You can't hover something unless your mouse can touch it. If there's text over-top, you can't touch the element behind... unless the text was somehow actually a part of hover elements.  Actually, depending on your actual situation (showing some code would help), this might work with a background image, as long so you don't need to select the text. But it would be a lot of CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the `h3` ignore mouse (*pointer*) events with

```
h3{ pointer-events:none; }
```

but this only works with FF/Chrome/Webkit

Comment: For IE support, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Answer (score 0):

Set the background of the grid elements to `background: transparent` and then give them a higher `z-index`?

Comment: the transition is on the background of the grid elements, so I can't get rid of the background.