# jquery absolute positioned element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with absolute positioned div's click. I am developing a website with jquery scrollpath and added extra layers to get parallax effect and top layer covers buttons in main layer and they cant be clicked, hovered, ect.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ugGgN/1/) is simple examlple:

```
<div class="body">
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b">
    <div class="element first">First</div>
    <div class="element second">Second</div>
</div>
</div>

.body {
    position relative;
}
.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
}
.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    z-index: 1;
}
.b .element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}
.b .element.first {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
.b .element.second {
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
}
```

I need to keep this html structure and ability to click div's in absolute positioned div with lower z-index. Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set `pointer-events` to `none` on the upper element to stop it reacting on mouse events.

```
pointer-events:none;
```

JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/ugGgN/5/

Cross browser support is very good these days: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

For more information on pointer-events please see the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events?v=example

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to track click events in the upper layer then you can achieve this using

```
pointer-events: none
```

on the upper layer.

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/ugGgN/6/

Or you can also make it work by forwarding click events through layers as `pointer-events: none` is not properly supported cross browser. Have a look at this link http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/

Answer (score 1):

The css way is good one, but as they said is no corss browser. Anyway, you can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie), on stackoverflow. You have two ways and if i were you i would use the [js method](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit) .

**Edit** : according to what you have i followed the js example and i got [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2A36/).

```
$('.a').on( 'click', function( event ){
    var clickPos = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
    $('.element').each(function(){
        var t = $(this),
            elemPos = [t.offset().left, t.offset().top],
            elemSize = [t.width(), t.height()];

        if (
            clickPos[0] > elemPos[0] && clickPos[0] < elemPos[0] + elemSize[0]
            && clickPos[1] > elemPos[1] && clickPos[1] < elemPos[1] + elemSize[1]
        ) t.trigger( 'click' );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The cross-browser way to solve this is to use `z-index` to position it on the layer above the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "pointer-events:none;" to the containing div of the absolutely positioned element. That way you will click trough the element.