# CSS wrapper div's background to cover content

Tags: css, z-index

I have 2 divs inside a wrapper div and I was wondering if it's possible to bring the #wrapper div on top of the content (#outer and #inner).

```
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="outer">
          <div id="inner"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want the #wrapper to add a transparent background without making any changes to the HTML. I have tried doing so using z-index without success.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nPpDE/

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: By "on top of", what do you mean? To apear above it's children?

Comment: No, in terms of layout a child can't appear behind its parent. You can change the opacity of the outer and inner divs to see through them to the wrapper div, or create an absolutely positioned new inner div that sits on top of the outer and inner divs.

Comment: No, that's the way the stacking order works.

Comment: Yes, to appear above its children. I was wondering if it's possible without having to add an extra div on top of everything as it kind of messes out the layout.

Comment: Adding a (semi) transparent background is as simple as using `rgba`, but a parent can't be above its child. I don't think you can do this withour changing the HTML.

Comment: Read about `stacking order` - http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/

Comment: I thought so. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Managed it using `:after`- http://jsfiddle.net/t6mMR/ -No extra html!

Like this:

```
#wrapper:after {
   position:relative;
   top:-200px;
   left:0px;
   content:"";
   width:400px;
   height:200px;
   display:block;
   background:rgba(255, 0, 0,0.5)
}
```

The pseudo-element is placed above the others, and a semi transparent background applied to it.

__

**EDIT:** A slightly different way of doing it- (see comment below) (using `position:absolute`

http://jsfiddle.net/t6mMR/1/

__

**Note-** To be able to "click through" the pseudo-element, add `pointer-events: none;` to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6mMR/1/

To get this to work in IE, see [css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie), it may help.

Comment: Nice solution, i just updated it abit, because position:absolute; is more suited (now it doesnt have a fixed height and width) http://jsfiddle.net/t6mMR/1/

Comment: @koningdavid Right I'll add this too.

Comment: I hope for you that this containers holds no links nor forms , they'll be underneath of pseudo-element :)

Comment: did you give it a try, cause bg is still there ?

Comment: @GCyrillus It is, but that's what the OP wanted. You can still interact with anything below it with the code I added.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t6mMR/2/ i meant IE9  ? others won't deal with rgba() anyway :)

Comment: I think you should  add this advise to your answer and this link too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: @GCyrillus Just found it myself :) I'll add it.

Comment: I actually need the #wrapper to be clickable so that's fine. @harley thank you very much.

Comment: @GCyrillus It might be useful for others though :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible.

However, it is possible when you add another div inside the #wrapper and position it with

```
position:absolute;
```

and give it a transparent color

http://jsfiddle.net/nPpDE/1/

EDIT: Harley's solution is better since the OP doesn't want to change the HTML

Comment: Thanks. That was my second option :)

Answer (score 1):

You can give the children `position: relative` and `z-index: -1` (or otherwise negative value), but I'm not sure how buggy that is or what the browser support is.

some more info available here: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Here's a quick example: http://codepen.io/Rykus0/full/jhwev

Otherwise, as others have said, you need to include a new element and position using either `absolute` or `fixed`

Comment: I use this solution sometimes but I was never sure it was "okay". Dev's feedback on in would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

?? and what about having opacity colors on inner containers and regular color on main container:

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    background:black;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
}
#outer{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    background: rgba(50,0,0,0.75);
}
#inner{
    position:relative;
    width:350px;
    height:200px;
        background:rgba(0,50,0,0.75);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

fiddle that goes with it :) http://jsfiddle.net/nPpDE/2/