# Disable tab in zurb foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation and have the following html:

```
<div class="section-container auto" data-section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Tab 1</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 1.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Tab 2</a></p>
    <div class="content" data-section-content>
      <p>Content of section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Is it posible to disable second tab? Tab button should be visble, but not clickable.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some CSS to disable it.

```
.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

**Edit**

With respect to Dolondro's comment and pointer events not working in IE, see [css 'pointer-events' property alternative for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)

Comment: As you're using Foundation 4, IE8 is out of the window anyway, but use of pointer events won't work in IE9 or IE10 either. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Good point, for info on pointer events in IE see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Comment: since i don't care much about IE, this was useful to me =)

Answer (score 0):

slightly dirty hack, but it will work everywhere (don't forget to add class 'disabled' to the

tag)

```
    $("[data-tabs] > li.disabled a").bind("click", function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom link class to only consider enabled tabs via `data-link-class` and then use the specified class only the enabled tabs.

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs data-link-class="enabled" id="disabled-tabs">
    <li class="enabled"><a>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

By default, foundation uses `tabs-title` for the link class, but you can override it.  In this example, I'm using `enabled` to only target enabled tabs.  Foundation will ignore the tabs without the `enabled` class.

You'll probably also want to disable pointer events on the disabled tabs so that the user doesn't think they can interact with the disabled tab.

```
.tabs li:not(.enabled) a {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```