# Ignore hover event completely for text on Raphael object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, raphael

I am binding hover events to Raphael circles. This all works well and as expected.

When drawing a text string "over" the circle, using Raphael, the text character "steals" the hover and the circle hover exits. When exiting the text character, into the circle, the hover is restored.

The text is obviously a new, different object. Can I disable hover events completely for this text object?

- I cannot draw the text behind the circle, as the circle has a solid color.
- I am not specifically binding any hover events to the text object

Are there ways to solve this?

```
var paper = Raphael("myMap", 721, 1017);
paper.clear();

newcircle.attr({ fill: "#727272", "cursor": "pointer", stroke: "#A4A2A2"});
paper.text(x, y, "X");
```

Comment: Have you tried `pointer-events:none;` for the paper?

Comment: Nope. Would that be a style?

Comment: Yeah, it'd go in the CSS for the object, I'm not sure if it's different in Raphael

Comment: Looks like you could do `papaer.node.setAttribute("pointer-events","none");`

Comment: That did it my friend... thanks! paper.text(x, y, "?").node.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none"); - Add it as an answer so I can mark it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `pointer-events:none;` for the object.

For you that'd look something like `paper.node.setAttribute("pointer-events","none");`

**From comments:** Actual fix: `paper.text(x, y, "?").node.setAttribute("pointer-events", "none");`

**Edit** For IE, the solution is more complex. You either have to use javascript [like this](http://jsbin.com/uhuto/1/edit) or a plugin [like this one](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/). I got this answer from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)