# Non-interacting text

Tags: javascript, html, css

If a custom placeholder element is positioned over an input, for instance with `position: absolute`, the input cannot be clicked.  An almost cross-browser solution is to make the placeholder "non-interacting":

```
.noninteracting {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, `pointer-events: none` is not supported in IE.  A number of alternatives have been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie), but they seem hacky and may be overkill for what I want to do.

**What is the least hacky cross-browser way to place text above other elements, but not allow the user to interact with it?**

Comment: Why don't you set the text's `z-index` so that it's positioned *behind* your `input`, and give your field a transparent background.

Comment: @JosephSilber I thought of that, but it falls under the 'hacky' category.

Comment: @1" - I'd say it's the least hacky way, but I guess it's a matter of opinion...

Comment: @JosephSilber Fair enough.  I've had issues with opacity in IE7 so I guess that colours my opinion.  You also have to remove the transparency of the input element if you remove the placeholder, but that's a minor issue.

Comment: @1" - Who said anything about using the `opacity` property? Just set the `input`'s `background-color` to `transparent`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also call focus on the input if your placeholder is clicked.

```
$(".placeholder").click( function(e){ $('.input').focus(); });
```

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that?  :)

Comment: Very true. I'd say most sites being created now don't work with out javascript. I'll try and think of another non js answer though.

Comment: @JoshC - I disagree that most sites don't work without JavaScript. Happens to be. you *sure can* log into this site without JavaScript. We should be building sites with graceful degradation (or progressive enhancement). I've posted a CSS-only solution above in the comments.

Comment: @JeffPowers This actually doesn't work in a subtle way: you lose control of where in the input the cursor is focused.

Comment: Ah-ha, that's a good call. I'm going to try and come up with another solution that also doesn't need js.

Comment: Actually, it's fine as long as you remove or hide the placeholder div when there's text in the input.  When there's no text in the input, it's fine to use this solution because the cursor only needs to go one place.

Comment: Oops, yeah I left that part out, I should have been more specific. Though as Joseph said this doesn't cover browsers with javascript disabled. My answer below covers all possible cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best option. It includes a number of different components but I believe it covers all possible scenarios.

Add a class "no-js" to the html element.

```
  <html class="no-js">
```

Each input field will have a label.

```
  <label class="no-js-label">Email Address</label>
```

If Javascript is enabled you will remove the class on the header, thus hiding the labels.

```
 .no-js-label { display:none; }
 .no-js .no-js-label { display:none; }
```

Then use an html5 placeholder with a polyfill. This list includes a number of options.
https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills