# pointer-events issue in IE browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Have a issue with `pointer-events:none;` it's working in latest browsers like chrome, mozilla but have a issue with IE browsers.

pls suggest any solution

Thanks

Comment: IE version? `pointer-events` for HTML is only supported in IE11+.

Answer (score 0):

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)**

Pointer-events is a Mozilla hack and where it has been implemented in Webkit browsers, you can see this in IE11.

There is however a solution I found:

**[Forwarding Mouse Events Through Layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)**

This uses a plugin that uses some not well known/understood properties of Javascript to take the mouse event and send it to another element.

There is also another Javascript solution **[here.](http://jsbin.com/uhuto)**

However, in IE (and Opera, and AFAIK all browsers), you could simply force a type of cursor on an element:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active, a:focus /*, * <-- add all tags?*/
{
    cursor: default;/*plain arrow*/
    text-decoration: none;/*No underline or something*/
    color: #07C;/*Default link colour*/
}
```

The result should be pretty similar to that of pointer-events: none;