# Click through an element, affecting what's behind it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I was going to make an overlay thing for my website where an element is fixed over the site and placed above everything.  But this means that nothing else behind the element can be effected.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hm6Js/1/) reproducing this problem.

You'll notice that you cannot highlight the black text, and the JavaScript event doesn't fire.

---

Here is the CSS + HTML I've used to create this problem:

**`HTML`**

```
<div id="main-container">
    <div id="container-content">You can't highlight me! D:</div>
    <div id="container-fixed"><div style="margin:90px auto;background:red;width:40px;height:40px;"></div>You cannot highlight the text behind this DIV.  It also doesn't fire click events.</div>
</div>
```

`main-container`: This holds the content.

`container-content`: This is the content behind the fixed DIV

`container-fixed`: This is the DIV the overlaps "container-content"

**`CSS`**

```
#main-container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 5%;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#container-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#container-fixed {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: red;
}
```

---

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? Both CSS and JavaScript (jQuery) answers are allowed.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Actually, I can select both the red and black text in the jsfidddle ( on Chrome 36)

Comment: I'm using Chromium 34 on Linux.  You can select, just not individual bits.  If you triple click it selects all the text.  Otherwise I cannot select text.  Also keep in mind, that I need JavaScript events to be fired too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use CSS [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse events, the value none instructs the mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.

```css
#container-content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you need support for IE 10 and lower, there's a [polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill).

Comment: Argh, why IE, why? D:

Comment: As all of us web developers know, IE is a bit slow to the game for a lot of things. On the bright side, quite a few cutting-edge features are [under consideration for the next version](https://status.modern.ie/).

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
#container-fixed{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) disables mouse interaction on the targeted element.
Please keep in mind that this CSS property is not supported by IE versions before 11.

Answer (score 1):

for IE10> browsers you have to calculate the position of the elements you want to be clicked through the higher level element and then do the thing you wanna do. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/hm6Js/7/

```
topo=$('#container-content').offset().top;
left=$('#container-content').offset().left;
right=$('#container-content').offset().left+$('#container-content').width();
bottom=$('#container-content').offset().top+$('#container-content').height();
$(document).click(function(e){
    if(e.pageX>=left && e.pageX<=right && e.pageY>=topo && e.pageY<=bottom){
        alert("This doesn't work.");
    }
});
```

as you can see in this example the alert only fires when you click on the `#container-content` element.

**NOTE:**

it is not the most efficient way if there are lots of elements that you want to be clicked through.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pointer events with css. 
Change your css for `#container-content` to this

```
#container-content{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}

#container-fixed {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0; left:0;
color:red;

    pointer-events: none /*the important thing*/
}
```

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hm6Js/6/)

a link to more information for pointer events can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)
This might not be cross browsers though so another dude suggests if this is an issue) to use javascript, to forward mouse events through layers. complete answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie)

Answer (score -3):

you can do this by adding `z-index`

```
#container-content {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Just setting the `z-index` doesn't allow to click through it.

Comment: tried on fiddle and it works

Comment: In the fiddle it works, but as described in the question `#container-fixed` is meant to be an overlay. Setting the `z-index` on `#container-content` places it above `#container-fixed`, so it's not an overlay anymore.