# how to click through a label?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a custom gantt chart which has a bar and a label on it. The bar of the chart is a a combination of small div and the label for the bar is placed in the first div.

I have created a rough version to simulate this here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6hjv82w/).I think the issue is due to  pointer-event:none; not supported in IE. I have set the following property in CSS for label

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.mylabel {
     pointer-events: none;
    left: 40px;
    position: absolute;  
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 2;
}
.rowDiv {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;    
    z-index: -1;
} 

</style>
</head>

<script>
function div1Click(){alert("Div1 clicked");}
function div2Click(){alert("Div2 clicked");}
function div3Click(){alert("Div3 clicked");}
</script>



<body>
<div style="width:95px;height:35px;overflow-y:hidden;z-index: -1;">
<div id="Div1" class="rowDiv" style="background-color:#b0c4de;" onClick="div1Click()"><label class="mylabel" >DiV 123</label></div>
<div id="Div2" class="rowDiv" style="background-color:#FF0000" onClick="div2Click()"></div>
<div id="Div3" class="rowDiv" style="background-color:#00FF00" onClick="div3Click()"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

On the click of each div it should open a popup corresponding to that div. However the label from the first div spans across all the other div. When i click on the label anywhere in div 2 or div 3, the click event for the first div is triggered instead of div 2 or Div 3.

The issue exist only in IE 10 and it works fine in Chrome.

Is there any way to make this work in IE 10.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you see warning message that you have to add code with fiddle link?

Comment: kindly do the needful of putting up a proper fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pointer events were introduced in IE11](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events), so will not work in 10 or below.

Check out [click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie) for some alternative ideas