# Click below elements of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

One example I can give:

```css
.nightly{
  z-index: 9000; 
  position: fixed; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="nightly">
</div>

<div class="body">
  <button>Test</button>
  <a href="#">Test 1</a>
</div>
```

Wanted to know how about the `div.nightly`" transparent "for clicks, or can click the button, link, etc. below it?

Answer (score 6):

Yep in your CSS add `pointer-events : none;` The clicks will pass through.

Comment: Bad IE [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)  but otherwise for sure it is easiest solution

Comment: That I did not know. Thank you so much!

Comment: One day I wish I can say "Who cares about IE?" :)

Answer (score 0):

For IE (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie#answer-17978065)):

```
//This is an IE fix because pointer-events does not work in IE
$(document).on('mousedown', '.nightly', function (e) {

    $(this).hide();
    var BottomElement = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    $(this).show();
    $(BottomElement).mousedown(); //Manually fire the event for desired underlying element

    return false;

});
```