# Interactively select DOM element

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know a library that provides an interactive selection mechanism highlighting the element the user is currently hovering with their mouse?

I have created a [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwochnik/oct53euy/) which demonstrates this mechanism.

If there is no existing library for this, I have the following issue with my own code: `pointer-events: none` is not supported in IE < 11 but I need a way of making the highlighting rectangle click-through.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855135/css-pointer-events-property-alternative-for-ie

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pure CSS, just by setting the background color with the :hover selector on any elements you want to be highlighted:

```
h1:hover, p:hover, li:hover
{
  background: rgba(127,127,127,0.5);
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/oct53euy/1/)